# Am I inherting base class along with superclass for multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

So I'm trying to wrap my head around this idea of multiple inheritance in C++. I've been working on some homework for the last couple of hours and have run into a road block, and it has to do with `MI`. So I have a `Package` class that things inherit from. `Letter` `Box` `Crate` Crate has the option of being either a `MetalCrate` or a `WoodCrate` My question is: `What is needed inside of the Crate class?`

**crate.h**

```
#ifndef CRATE_H
#define CRATE_H

#include "package.h"

class Crate: public Package{
public:
  Crate();
  Crate(double price, int weight, int trackingNumber);

  double cost();
};

#endif
```

Cost is a virtual function from package that all classes have their own implementation for. `I shouldn't have to define all the public variables that I defined inside of Package inside the Crate class` correct? I've been reading stuff online and can't seem to wrap my head around what is needed inside the Crate class.

**Package.h**

```
class Package{

protected:
  double price;
  int weight;
  int trackingNumber;

public:
  Package();
  Package(double price, int weight, int trackingNumber);

  void setWeight(int weight);
  void setPrice(int price);
  void setTrack(int track);
  double getPrice();
  int getWeight();
  int getTrack();

  virtual double cost() = 0;
  ~Package();
};
```

**MetalCrate.h**

```
class MetalCrate: public Crate, public Package{
public:
  MetalCrate();
  MetalCrate(double price, int weight, int trackingNumber);

  double cost();
};
```

Those are what my classes look like. Please help, thank you in advance.

`metalcrate.h:16:7: warning: direct base ‘Package’ inaccessible in ‘MetalCrate’ due to ambiguity [enabled by default] class MetalCrate: public Crate, public virtual Package{ this is the error i get when i try to compile. i'm trying to get my wood/metal crate to inherit from crate and package –`

DISCUSSION WAS MOVED TO A CHAT WHERE THINGS WERE EXPLAINED IN A MUCH MORE DETAILED MANNER

Comment: The best way to use C++ multiple inheritance is to avoid it entirely

Comment: Also, could you make your question a little clearer? I'm happy to answer but I'm not sure what you're asking exactly.

Comment: Where's the multiple inheritance? `Crate` has just one parent class.

Comment: @Pradhan oops I forgot to add my metal crate class. actually i'm not even sure on how to set the metal crate class up properly

Comment: @Pradhan I think he's confused it with multiple classes inheriting

Comment: @OMGtechy everything seems to be working fine for me as far as creating a package that is a letter or box. but when i try to make metal or wood crate from a crate that inherits from package i have issues

Comment: @kevorski and what issues are those exactly? The more specific you are the more I can help you. For example, what you're trying to do and what error comes up when you try to do it will help a lot.

Comment: @OMGtechy `metalcrate.h:16:7: warning: direct base ‘Package’ inaccessible in ‘MetalCrate’ due to ambiguity [enabled by default]
 class MetalCrate: public Crate, public virtual Package{`

this is the error i get when i try to compile. i'm trying to get my wood/metal crate to inherit from crate and package

Comment: @kevorski you don't need to inherit from package in metalcrate, it's passed on from crate :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58527/discussion-between-kevorski-and-omgtechy).

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of structuring your code, but in terms of object-oriented design, it is generally best not to include any state or implementation in your base classes and to contain state and implementation only in your final, concrete classes. One reason is that it is common to run into a case where an implementation is vastly different than the set of implementations considered by the base class, and thus the storage used by the base becomes unsuitable for a particular implementation. Another reason is that providing implementation in the base class may impose additional invariants and constraints on implementations that implementations may be unaware of or that are easy to break.

A better way of structuring this, in short, would be:

```
class Package {
  public:
    virtual ~Package();
    virtual double getPrice() const = 0;
    virtual int getWeight() const = 0;
    virtual int getTrack() const = 0;
    virtual double cost() const = 0;

  protected:
    Package();
};
```

And then, to create a separate class the encapsulates the common elements (or to create an "AbstractPackage" that other instances of package can optionally inherit from). This makes it possible for you to create an implementation of Package which doesn't carry around the additional baggage of the default implementation/variables if it is not applicable to some alternative implementation. In addition, even for your "AbstractPackage", you should never make variables "protected" or "public"; all member variables should be "private" (if your derived classes need access, consider a "protected" accessor).

Comment: so should i be using the setters inside of the subclasses, say letter or box to set the weights and prices and such?

Comment: That or using the base constructor of the "AbstractPackage". You should also consider whether the values need to be mutable after construction; where possible, it's often better/cleaner to provide such configuration at construction and then make the state immutable once the object has been successfully created, though this really depends on more details regarding your usage/application.